# How to set private static string value from model class list string value

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I want to set private static string value from model class list string value. Example- **private static final String DOWNLOAD_PATH = “ ”;** Now I want to set value to **DOWNLOAD_PATH** from **String url = getIntent().getStringExtra(“download_url”);**. I need help.

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly is not working?

Comment: Now working. Just I change- **private static final String DOWNLOAD_PATH = “ ”;**  to **private Uri DOWNLOAD_PATH;**